# How to exclude records from Regular Expression condition in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-like

In one of my query I do not want Regular Expression condition in **WHERE** clause. It means the query should exclude Regular expression condition. 
Eg:- `select ........   where regexp_like(col, '[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z0-9]')`

whatever we are getting records from the above query I do not want.
In the above code i do not want this regular expression in the **WHERE** clause. How to exclude this condition so that i can filter my condition & query .

Comment: Describe what you're trying to do!

Comment: You can't easily do the same logic as your current regex is doing, without using a regex.

Comment: That above query is not working, it shows an error because you use it (regex) the wrong way in oracle. Read the manual of `REGEXP_LIKE` first then try again later.

Comment: maybe you can try `where columnName not like '[a-zA-Z]%' ` it's working on mssql

Comment: @HarunKARATAŞ Not working that way in oracle

Comment: We  would prefer a question that asks what you want rather than what you don't want

Comment: Heh, that's funny. You don't want to use regular expression *because it shows an error*. I'd rather try to fix that *error*. It is obvious that `REGEXP_LIKE` you posted is invalid; a quick view at the documentation would reveal why. If you could describe what you want (as @Kaushik has already said), it would be easier to assist.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen according to the logic if I use `regexp_like` then i find only selected data which do not want. It means exclude the data which is get from `regexp_like`.

Comment: Wanting to keep or exclude based on a regex does not change that you need to use a regex.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If in a table 500 records are there and when i use `regexp_like` in the WHERE clause then i got 100 records. But i do not want these 100 records. I want remaining 400 records.

Comment: Then just remove NOT.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen NOT has been remove but i do not want the criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `not`?

```
where not regexp_like(col, '[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z0-9]')
```

You might need to take `NULL`s into account as well:

```
where not regexp_like(col, '[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z0-9]') or col is null
```